# Can I set the Hover on a link in partner portal?

Tags: partner-portal, configuration

I have users in the partner portal. They use the activity a lot. They want to be able to call up the hover feature when the hover over a link, such as account etc. Is this possible in the partner portal?

Comment: This works exactly the same in the Partner Portal as it does in the standard GUI. Or are you referring to some specific part of Activities functionality?

Comment: I have tested this, in my test i created a task that had an account in the related to field. I created this task using the one record type. I was then able to hover over the related to field and the account details popped up. However when I looked at this same task in the partner portal the hover did not produce any detail popup.

Comment: I tried to replicate but in my Partner Community it works correctly. I can't recall this not working in Partner Portal..